# How to get selected value from select list in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get selected value from form to a controller function, 
Here is my code

```
<form action='examplefunction'     method='POST'>

<select name='chapter'>
<option value='Select1'>Select1   
<option value='Select2'>Select2 
<option value='Select3'>Select3 
<option value='Select4'>Select4 
<option value='Select5'>Select5 
</select>
</form>
```

Controller function

```
public function examplefunction()
{
 echo $_POST['chapter'];
}
```

If I select `Select3` & submit, it shows error in this function saying that "Undefined index: chapter". How can I get this value in controller function?

Comment: What framework are you using? Are you sure you put correct action url in form attribute? You should recheck this : <form action='examplefunction'

Comment: yes I am sure I used controller name before

Answer (score 1):

In view

```
<form action='<?php echo base_url()?>controller_name/examplefunction' method='post'>//change URL and Method

    <select name='chapter'>
        <option value='Select1'>Select1
        <option value='Select2'>Select2
        <option value='Select3'>Select3
        <option value='Select4'>Select4
        <option value='Select5'>Select5
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"> //add this
</form>
```

in Controller

```
function examplefunction()
{
    $chapter=$_POST['chapter'];
    echo $chapter;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `<select name='chapter'>` to `<select name='chapter[]'>` and in the handler php file use something like this

```
    $chapter=$_POST['chapter'];
    if ($chapter){
     foreach ($chapter as $t){echo 'You selected ',$t,'<br />';}
    }
```

Comment: not a codeigniter standerd and why need an array name

Comment: What is this suppose to be? =/